# Is it possible to disable click listener on colorbox image?

Tags: javascript, colorbox

How can I disable the default behavior of going to the next image when clicking on the current image using colorbox?

[fiddle showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/LgwkLck0/)http://jsfiddle.net/LgwkLck0/

```
$.each($('.colorbox'), function(i, val) {
    $(val).colorbox({
        rel: "images",
        photo: true,
        onComplete: function() {
            //TODO: remove click listener
            // $('.cboxPhoto').unbind('click');
            // $('.cboxPhoto')[0].removeEventListener('click');
            // Does not work
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, you would use javascript.  Gotta post your codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer here:
https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/668

```
$('a.example').colorbox({onComplete: function(){
    $('.cboxPhoto')[0].onclick = null;
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about colorbox, but since its based on jQuery, you should be able to overload the click event and write a little bit of code to handle the issue, but if you can post some code I might be able to edit this with more information

Answer (score 0):

The solution didn't works for me so I used the same idea that works:

```
$('selector').colorbox({
    onComplete: function() {
        $('#colorbox').find('.cboxPhoto').off('click');
    }
});
```